# Error in Java Constructors (cannot find the symbol)

Tags: java

I created a class named Invoice that holds an invoice number, balance due, and
three fields representing the month, day, and year when the balance is due.
Create a constructor that accepts values for all five data fields. Within the
constructor, assign each argument to the appropriate field with the following
exceptions:

1. If an invoice number is less than 1000, force the invoice number to 0.
2. If the month field is less than 1 or greater than 12, force the month field to 0.
3. If the day field is less than 1 or greater than 31, force the
   day field to 0.
4. If the year field is less than 2011 or greater than 2017, force the year field to 0.

In the Invoice class, include a display method that displays all the fields on an
Invoice object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Invoice

{

  private int inNum;
  private double balDue;
  private int m;
  private int d;
  private int yy;

   public void setinNum(int inv)
   {
     inNum = inv;
     if(inv < 1000)
     inv = 0;
   }

   public int getinNum()
   {
     return inNum()
   }

   public void setbalDue(double bal)
   {
     balDue = bal;
   } 

   public double getbalDue()
   {
     return balDue()
   }


   public void setm(int month)
   {
     m = month;
        if(month < 1 || month >12)
        month = 0;
     }

   public int getm()
  {
     return m()
  }

  public void setd(int days)
  {
   d = days;
    if(days < 1 || days > 31)
    days = 0;
   }

  public int getd()
  {
    return d()
  }

  public void setyy(int years)
  {
   yy = years;
    if(years < 2011 || years > 2017)
    years = 0;
  }

 public int getyy()
 {
   return yy()
}



        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
         double inNum;

         int m, d, yy;
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please type your invoice number: ");
          inNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12) ");
          m = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.print("What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31) ");
          d = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.print("What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) ");
          yy = keyboard.nextInt();

        if((inNum >= 1000) && (m <= 12 && d <= 31 && yy >= 2011) && yy <= 2017)
          System.out.print("Your invoice number is " + inNum + " and your balance due is on " +  m + "/" + d + "/" + yy);
        else
          if((inNum >= 1000) && (m<=12 || m <= 0) && (d <= 31 && yy >= 2011) && yy <= 2017)
           System.out.println("Error! Invalid Month Input.");
        else
          System.out.println("Error!"); 



         }

      }
```

Now I have a logical error, I was trying to force the month to output this:

1. If an invoice number is less than 1000, force the invoice number to 0.
2. If the month field is less than 1 or greater than 12, force the month field to 0.
3. If the day field is less than 1 or greater than 31, force the
   day field to 0.
4. If the year field is less than 2011 or greater than 2017, force the year field to 0.

But I don't know how can I force the fields to 0. This was the output when I tried to run it:

Please type your invoice number: 999

What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12) 12

What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31) 2012

What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) 12

Your invoice number is 999.0 and your balance due is on 12/2012/12

Comment: inNum(); is not a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try the following code for your issue

```
    public class Invoice
{


  private int inNum;
  private double balDue;
  private int m;
  private int d;
  private int yy;

public Invoice(int inNum, double balDue, int m, int d, int yy) {
    super();
    setInNum(inNum);
    setBalDue(balDue);
    setM(m);
    setD(d);
    setYy(yy);
}


public int getInNum() {
    return inNum;
}




public void setInNum(int inNum) {
    if(inNum < 1000)
        this.inNum = 0;
    else
        this.inNum = inNum;
}




public double getBalDue() {
    return balDue;
}




public void setBalDue(double balDue) {
    this.balDue = balDue;
}




public int getM() {
    return m;
}




public void setM(int m) {
    if(m < 1 || m > 12)
        this.m = 0;
    else
        this.m = m;
}




public int getD() {
    return d;
}




public void setD(int d) {
    if(d < 1 || d > 31)
        this.d = 0;
    else
        this.d = d;

}




public int getYy() {
    return yy;
}




public void setYy(int yy) {
    if(yy < 2011 || yy > 2017)
        this.m = 0;
    else
        this.yy =yy;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice (100, 3000, 14, 29, 2016);
    System.out.println(invoice.getInNum() +" "+ invoice.getBalDue() +" "+ invoice.getM() +" "+ invoice.getD() +" "+ invoice.getYy());


}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! However, I need the user to be able to input invoice number and the balance due dates. What codes should I add?

Comment: welcome, I suggest you to use  Scanner class which is present in java.util package so you import this package in our program.

Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
Following methods of Scanner class are used in the program below :-
1) nextInt to input an integer
2) nextFloat to input a float
3) nextLine to input a string. in main you should have something like this String fileName;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the file name in .txt");
  fileName = in.nextLine();

Comment: This is what I put    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please type your invoice number: ");
   inNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12) ");
   m = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.print("What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31) ");
   d = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.print("What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) ");
   yy = keyboard.nextInt();      but it displays an error         error: non-static variable inNum cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1):

`return inNum();` is the problem. `inNum` is a *field* not a *method*. use `return inNum`

Comment: Thanks! I also have to Write an application containing a main() method that declares several Invoice objects, proving that all the statements in the constructor operate as specified. How can I call the constructors in main() method?

Comment: @Chrissy - use `new Invoice()` or `new Invoice(argsToConstructor)` from `main()`. The correct constructors will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`inNum` is a variable and not a method, so remove parentheses `()` from :

```
  return inNum();
```

change it to

```
  return inNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return  the content of the filed `inNum` you have to remove the parentheses :

```
public int getinNum()
   {
     return inNum;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

While returning the value do not write "()" after the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your program at many place you have mistake just replace the method to simple varible
that changes are listed below :

```
return inNum() to return  inNum;
return balDue() to return  balDue
return m() to return m
return d() to return d
return yy() to return yy
```

I hope, it will work after changes

Comment: Thanks! I also have to Write an application containing a main() method that declares several Invoice objects, proving that all the statements in the constructor operate as specified. How can I call the constructors in main() method?